# Hello world printf issues in assembly

Tags: assembly

I've been searching for hours on how to fix this. Run it by typing

```
nasm -f elf64  hello.asm
ld -s -o hello hello.o
```

and get the following:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
hello.o: In function `main':
hello.asm:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `printf'
```

If I do `gcc hello.o`, then `./a.out` it works, but then there's an extra `.a` file in the repository.

Fairly new to this, and in a compressed summer course, the professor is making us learn Linux and github to turn in our assignments! Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
;hello.asm

    bits 64
    global main
    extern printf

    section .text
main:
    ; function setup
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    ;
    lea     rdi, [rel message]
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf

    ; function return
    mov     eax, 0
    add     rsp, 32
    pop     rbp
    ret

    section .data
message: db      'Course: COSC2425 Lab2',0x0D,0x0a,'Student: firstname     lastname',0x0D,0x0a,'Project: Nasm Hello World'
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in assembly

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use gcc. `gcc -o hello hello.o`. If you wish to invoke ld yourself - `ld -o hello hello.o -e main -lc` might shut it up.

Comment: The `gcc` route is your best bet. The `-e main` entry point def will likely fail. A good way to look at the order and linkage dependencies is to use `gcc -v` e.g.  `gcc -v -o hello hello.o` From than you can discern what is needed. (**note** when linking libc functions into an assembly program (instead of the other way around) it is generally best to let `gcc` worry about the linking ordering and dependencies)

Comment: Ah yes. `-e main` will make `main` the entrypoint, but we can't `ret` from it. Good catch, David!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with nasm but with gas procedure is the following. Create object:

```
as -o hello.o hello.s
```

Now since you are calling printf linking is against ld-linux.so.2, according to Richard Bloom or adjusted for 64 bit architecture

```
ld --dynamic-linker /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o hello -lc hello.o
```

Double check is it right location of ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 in your Linux it may be elsewhere. BTW your code is segfaulting on exit. Only way I could make it to exit normally is:

```
    global _start
    extern printf
    section .text
_start:
    mov     rdi, format
    mov     rsi, message
    mov     rax, 0
    call    printf
    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0
    int 80h
    section .data
message: db      'Course: COSC2425 Lab2',0x0a,'Student: firstname     lastname',0x0a,'Project: Nasm Hello World',0x0a,0
format:    db '%s', 0
```

`main` is renamed to `_start` to eliminate linker warning.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is part of the standard C library. Compiling your program with `gcc` automatically adds this library when its linked. If you are using `ld` manually, you need you must link the library with your program. Try this:

```
ld -I/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc -s -o hello hello.o
```

Also, by default, `ld` will look for a global label called `_start`, which is where your program execution will begin. You either need to change your `global main` to `global _start` and `main:` to `_start:` or you need to tell `ld` where your program starts by using this:

```
ld -I/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc -e main -s -o hello hello.o
```

Comment: Wrong order -- the library needs to be *after* the object files -- if its before, then symbol won't yet be referenced when it links the library, so it won't pull it in, leading to the same error...

Comment: @ChrisDodd - `gcc` cares about order. `ld` doesn't. It can be anywhere.

Comment: So you have actually confirmed that the OP source will link and produce a working executable with what you propose as an answer?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - yes. I just compiled and linked it without any errors.

Comment: I can compile and link it without any errors. Have you tried to run what you compiled? The resulting `elf` will not run.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - You're right. Bash is saying it can't find the file.

Comment: I've been down this frustrating road many times. If you look at a comparison of the executables that result from `gcc -o hello hello.o` and what results from a manual `ld` (without the long ordered string used by `gcc`) you will find only a few bytes difference, but that is the difference between `No such file or directory` and running.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Just found a solution. I'm using Ubuntu and I have to add this :`-I/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. It has to do with the fact that `ld` is trying to link with a 32-bit `ld` library instead of 64-bit. After printing the data, it will die with a segmentation fault, but that's because of your comment above about not being able to `ret` from it.

Comment: When I am working with assembly sources like this, I generally compile with `gcc -v` once, then take the resulting 10 lines of linkage and libraries and simply make a linker script substituting the ouputfile name and object file as needed. It will begin with something similar to `ld --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o $ofn .... -L linker search paths ... $obj ... -lgcc ...  crtend.o ... crtn.o ` That's again why there is no quick linker string for including libc functions in an assembly source.

Comment: Why not just use `gcc` to link.

Comment: @Jester - OP says he doesn't want to.